# Using 'expression' to incorporate mathtype in R Plot

Tags: r, plot, expression

I want to incorporate a greater than or equal to sign into my plot produced using the software package R.  However, it doesn't end up justifying correctly.  For example:

```
plot(1:10,1:10,col=-1)
text(5,5,expression(paste('Data used\n',phantom(x)>=5,' units')),pos=3)
```

I would like everything to be centered and still split onto two lines.
[image: Example]

Comment: There are methods other than `atop` but it didn't seem they were needed here. The comma is actually creating a separate expression item. You should spend more time studying the help page for `?plotmath`. Also read about the use of `bquote` and `substitute`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `\n` after the `Data used`. Should do the trick

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @alexey-ferapontov, but I would like the text to be split onto two separate lines and centered.  I would like to find a way to do this without having to call the text() function twice.  Any ideas?  Sorry the post wasn't that clear.

Comment: `plot(1:10,1:10,col=1)
text(5,5,paste("Data used", "\n\u22655 units"),adj = c(0,0))`